# Why is the color of the moon so similar to the clouds?

Tags: the-moon, naked-eye

[image]

Why the moon looks like the cloud-structure on the blue sky among the clouds?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please try to state in quantitative terms what you wish to learn.

Comment: The moon reflects light from the sun and it's surface on a black pitch dark background make it look likes it's silver/white/shades of gray. At daylight hours the sky looks like it's blue (it's a complex light effect on the atmosphere) so the moon appears in the above picture in a blue background

Comment: I tried to understand your post, and then I improved it to show, what I've understood from it. Is it okay?

Comment: VtC reviewers: please check [pending edit](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14083) before voting.

Comment: If you look at the picture, the Moon is roughly the same color as the thin clouds, but not the thick ones.   The moon is visibly greyish with darker spots.   The clouds, when thin and partially transparent appear a similar greyish color to the moon.   The thicker white clouds are a different color than the moon.

Answer (score 2):

The Moon is a dark gray in color -- it reflects light poorly but uniformly. (Its color is about the same  as fresh asphalt!  It's albedo is about 12%)  Clouds are (usually) light gray with an albedo ranging from 10% to 90%.

Both the Moon and the clouds shine by reflected sunlight, so they're both the same color. (Clouds usually have a greater surface brightness owing to their lower albedo.)

Answer (score 1):

The moon has dark and bright areas.

When it is visible in the daytime the bright areas appear roughly as bright as clouds, but the dark areas have no light to add to the scene and we are just left with the blue light from the sky generally.

The sky blue is not as bright as the clouds or the moon, at least when it's visible like this (typically near the end of day and early morning) so it does not conceal the bright clouds or the moon's brighter parts.

Answer (score -1):

Sry Guys ;) english is not my main language so maybe i mesed in question :) still  i think i found the answer , it serms  everything on a blue sky would look cloudish ? My main concern was why moon looks more cloudish than clouds moonish ;) but now i think its just the contecst ;)
Thx

Comment: Don't edit your question in an answer -- edit the original question.